# Why is $f$ doesn't have the intermediate value property?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

$f$, defined on $(0,2)$ doesn't have the intermediate value property: 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x \in (0,1) \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x \in [1,2) \end{cases} $$

Whereas, $g$ defined on $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ has the the intermediate value property: 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x \in (0,1) \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x \in (1,2) \end{cases} $$

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the second function is not defined at 1.  That should be your key point to looking for problems:  In the first function,  if you take the values $x=\frac 1 2$ and x=1,  you see that the values of the range are $[\frac 1 2,1)$ along with 0,  so no value between 0 and $\frac 1 2$ are hit.  This isn't a problem in the second function because the intermediate value property only holds for whole intervals on which the function is defined.

Comment: Right, Thank you. I guess I needed a refresh :)

Comment: No problem! enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Look, there is no $x$ for $f(x)=1$